# How to reject a request on 'rate limit' in a patched Boto client, allowing the boto to automatically retry

Tags: python, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I would like to instrument boto3 client, allowing it to block request on rate limit.
My code is based on the [Instana instrumentation for boto client](https://github.com/instana/python-sensor/blob/master/instana/instrumentation/boto3_inst.py), which acts like a 'read' instrumentation that only collects data and exports it.

> I would like to instrument a logic that blocks a request on rate limit, in a way that will cause the boto client to automatically retry sending the request (according to the boto retry settings).

Instana code snippet (with my raise_429_if_rate_limit_reached addition):

```
@wrapt.patch_function_wrapper('botocore.client', 'BaseClient._make_api_call')
def make_api_call_with_instana(wrapped, instance, arg_list, kwargs):
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    active_tracer = get_active_tracer()

    # If we're not tracing, just return
    if active_tracer is None:
        return wrapped(*arg_list, **kwargs)

    with active_tracer.start_active_span("boto3", child_of=active_tracer.active_span) as scope:
        try:
            <... collect request info ...>

        except Exception as exc:
            logger.debug("make_api_call_with_instana: collect error", exc_info=True)

        # check for rate limit and block request on 429 Status
        raise_429_if_rate_limit_reached()

        try:
            result = wrapped(*arg_list, **kwargs)
            <... collect response info ...>
            return result
        except Exception as exc:
            scope.span.mark_as_errored({'error': exc})
            raise
```

So in this patching, if we raise an exception instead of calling the `wrapped` method, no retry would take place.

The retry logic of boto only takes places further down the code, inside `BaseClient._send_request` method. The call hierarchy is:

> _make_api_call -> _make_request -> endpoint.make_request -> endpoint._send_request -> endpoint._get_response

So where exactly can I add my patching logic?

- inside `endpoint._get_response` method?
- inside `endpoint._do_get_response` method?
- elsewhere?

Thanks a lot.